# Using Series to Compute Residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Take the function z $ \to$ $\frac{z^2 +3z - 1}{z+2}$.  Expanding the numerator in powers we obtain an initial term, a first derivative term and a second derivative term.  This initial term, the '$0$th' derivative of the function, is -3 and is the residue.  Why is the -1st power not the residue as is usually the case?

Comment: Please be clear: is that $\,\frac{1}{z}+2\,$ or $\,\frac{1}{z+2}\,$ ...?

Comment: or maybe even $\dfrac{z^2+3z-1}{z+2}$?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want the residue at $\,z=-2\,$ , so

$$\frac{z^2+3z-1}{z+2}=\frac{(z+2)^2-(z+2)-3}{z+2}=-\frac{3}{z+2}-1+(z+2)$$

and thus the residue (i.e., the coefficient of $\,(z+2)^{-1}\,$ ) indeed is $\,-3\,$ ...Perhaps you forgot to divide by that $\,z+2\,$ in the denominator?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  The book's answer made it seem as though this wasn't the case.  Thank you.